# Mouse enters the second monitor at different positions

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse-cursor

When my mouse cursor is in monitor one it can be at height X, but when I move it horizontally to monitor 2, suddenly it's at height X+2cm. How do I fix this?

[image: Picture]

From the picture above you can see that when I have my mouse on the left and drag it horizontally to the right, following that red line trajectory, it suddenly jumps up. Is there a way to calibrate this in windows 10?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on the desktop -> `Display Settings` and align your monitors with the mouse (drag-drop)

[image: Align the monitors by drag-drop]

Answer (score 0):

The path of the mouse is defined by pixels, not by physical dimensions. This implies:

- If your monitors have exactly the same vertical PPI, you can fiddle with the vertical alignment of the screens - either by physically moving them or by adapting the display layout in the control panel.
- If your monitors do not have the exact same vertical PPI, there is no way to make the mouse transitions exact for all screen positions. You can though try to make them exact in the middle and so reduce the offset at the top or bottom.